# How to load an external HTML page within a specific JavaScript code? E.g. Within a JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to this website and not sure how it works and whether anybody would reply to my question or not, but worth a try, so will post my question here! :)

Basically I've a HTML page which contains some  within different parts of the page and here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to My 1st JavaScript Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
//
var parameter = document.location.search.replace("?", "").replace("=", "");

// IF NO PARAMETER
if (!document.location.search || !parameter) {
    document.write("No parameter is defined. Please either set ?pictures, ?videos or ?music");

// IF PARAMETER
} else {
    // IF GAMES
    if (parameter == "pictures") {
        // FOR EXAMPLE INCLUDE THE PICTURES.HTML

    // IF VIDEOS
    } else if (parameter == "videos") {
        // FOR EXAMPLE INCLUDE THE VIDEOS.HTML

    // IF MUSIC
    } else if (parameter == "music") {
        // FOR EXAMPLE INCLUDE THE MUSIC.HTML
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This page would load different things according to the URL parameter that I've set, so when different URL parameters is called, I want to load different external HTML pages within the same page, and don't want to use iframe and such!
Is this possible or not? Please have a look at my code above!

In PHP we use:

```
<?php
    include ("./includes/music.html");
?>
```

But I don't know how to do this in JavaScript! Could somebody please help me with this!

Thanks :)

Comment: You really should be using a `<div>` or `<span>` and an `element.innerHTML = ` rather than `document.write`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Ajax, something like this:

```
function include(page) {
    var rq = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        try { rq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch(o) { try { rq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch(e) {} }
    }
    if(rq) {
        try {
            rq.open("GET", page, false);
            rq.send(null);
            document.body.innerHTML = rq.responseText;
        } catch(ex) {
            // Provide a fallback here, probably a redirect
        }
    } else {
         // Provide a fallback here, probably a redirect
    }
}
```

Comment: Internet Explorer (I believe 8 and previous, not sure) use `ActiveXObject`s instead of the `XMLHttpReqest` that other browsers use. There are two ActiveX objects that can be used - Msxml2.XMLHTTP and Microsoft.XMLHTTP, the latter being the older one that only works with 6 and earlier (I think). So we attempt to use the new one first, and if not, we use the old one.

Comment: Thanks for reply! :) Is there another way to do this, something simpler that doesn't requires libraries and of course AJAX, I'm asking because on the exam I need to explain everything and as I'm new in JS, then I'll probably having problem when explaining... thanks

Comment: @minitech It's IE 6 and below that need activex :). I know about mcirosoft.xmlhttp. I thought IE 7 and 8 had XMLHttpRequest build in

Comment: No, there is really no other way. (There's also really no reason why you would want to do this in real life where Ajax is applicable.) @Raynos: Okay. So? Msxml2 = IE6 and Microsoft = IE5.5 or less.

Comment: Thank you all for being so helpful! I appreciate it... :) I think is time to learn AJAX as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a templating engine to load templates with data.

There are many templating engines like [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/), [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), [jQuery-tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/).

The general idea is to request some a template file from the server based on your URL and use the templating engine to render it. You can also request JSON data to populate your template with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't have to use JavaScript libraries as well as server side programming language such as PHP! I've an exam on Wednesday and there are number of questions, and this is one of those... :)

Comment: @user then you'll need to use a `XMLHTTPRequest` or an iframe

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with learning a new library, the simplest way is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its [load](http://api.jquery.com/load) method.

There are some other cross-platform ways of using XmlHttpRequest objects to get an HTML page, but jQuery's is by far the simplest.